# Action Reaction pair

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

I have heard many physicists emphasize on the fact that "Action Reaction Pair do not cancel each other". Can you explain what they mean by  that? If the action and reaction do not cancel each other, why does a box placed placed on the ground remain stationary? Aren't the weight of the box and normal force cancelling each other? I'm so confused. Please help me

Comment: The action reaction pair refers to forces applied on different bodies. The reaction of the ground (can) balances the force exerted on it (weight of your box) so the body stays still.

Comment: In what context? References?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following diagram,

[image]

In case of vertical equilibrium, the upper block pushes the black box down with a normal reaction (which happens to be equal to its weight) and the black box provides the normal force or reaction (of the same magnitude) to the red box so that the net force on the red box becomes $0$, but these two forces (normal force due to red box and the normal force due to black box ) act on two different bodies, so they cannot cancel each other out.

***The red box pushes the black box by the normal reaction not by its weight.***